# QA SQL tables against historical data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two databases (MS SQL Server); one with a current set of reporting tables and another with last week's set of reporting tables. Each week I would like to compare all the measures in each (though from week to week the row count may vary) to the previous week's and make sure my QTD and YTD numbers are increasing. The order for the rows may be different each week, so whatever I go with must take that into account.

Another consideration is that I have around 50 of these tables to compare, so doing each manually is not going to be an option. It would also be great to have some sort of error log, for like when there is a value that is not higher YTD this week than last week.

Current Week

```
+-------+------------+--------+
| Item  | TimePeriod | Number |
+-------+------------+--------+
| Pigs  | QTD        |     28 |
| Pigs  | YTD        |     86 |
| Cows  | QTD        |      7 |
| Cows  | YTD        |      9 |
| Bears | QTD        |     67 |
| Bears | YTD        |    132 |
+-------+------------+--------+
```

Previous Week

```
+-------+------------+--------+
| Item  | TimePeriod | Number |
+-------+------------+--------+
| Bears | QTD        |     55 |
| Bears | YTD        |    120 |
| Pigs  | QTD        |     22 |
| Pigs  | YTD        |     80 |
| Cows  | QTD        |      5 |
| Cows  | YTD        |     10 |
+-------+------------+--------+
```

Error

Error: Cows YTD Current Week-9 Prev Week-10

Comment: Is your desired result the error log?  Does the DB name change each week or will "CurrentDB" and "PreviousDB" names always be consistent?  How do we know what all 50 tables are?  Is there some sort of pattern that the names match?

Comment: Yes, the desired result is the error log. The current DB name does not change, the previous DB will be the current DB with last week's date appended to the end. We know all 50 tables. I'm not sure about the last question about the pattern the names match, can you clarify?

Comment: @dvoery In the desired log output: `Error: Cows YTD Current Week-9 Prev Week-10`What do `-9`and `-10` symbolise? Is it part of the table name or is it the `Number`field?

Comment: @jpw It is the Number field. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this would do:

```
SELECT 'Error ' + CW.TimePeriod + ' Current week:' + CAST(CW.Number AS VARCHAR) + ' Prev week:' + CAST(PW.Number AS VARCHAR)
FROM [Current Week DB].Table CW 
INNER JOIN [Previous DB].Table PW ON 
  CW.ITEM=PW.ITEM 
  AND CW.TIMEPERIOD=PW.TIMEPERIOD 
  AND CW.Number=PW.Number
```

Joining on all columns will give the rows that haven't changed between the tables. The identifiers for the tables needs to be changed obviously.

Comment: Table names are the same, you've got to join across databases.

Comment: Oh right, misread the question... Shouldn't the logic be sound though after pointing the tables to the correct databases?

Comment: Except that you can't inner join, you have to outer join since there won't be the same number of rows in each table.  I assume that the Current could have more than the Previous.

Comment: Why can't I do inner join? It shouldn't matter if Current has more rows than Previous as it's the rows that haven't changed we want to log if I understood the question right.

Comment: Hmmm.  You may be right.  You'd have to check with the OP.  I'm certain that if we had a row in Previous and did not have a row in Current, that would be an error condition.  But only the OP can tell us if that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in your question justifies using either multiple databases *or* multiple tables.

Instead, consider using a table like this.

```
ITEM     TIMEPERIOD  WEEKNUM     NUMBER
Bears    QTD         2013-26     67
Bears    QTD         2013-25     55
Bears    YTD         2013-26     132
Bears    YTD         2013-25     120
Cows     QTD         2013-26     7
Cows     QTD         2013-25     5
Cows     YTD         2013-26     9
Cows     YTD         2013-25     10
Pigs     QTD         2013-26     28
Pigs     QTD         2013-25     22
Pigs     YTD         2013-26     86
Pigs     YTD         2013-25     80
```

Then the essential query is *relatively* simple and straightforward if you have SQL Server 2012.

```
select 
    item, timeperiod, weeknum, number,
    number - lead (number) 
             over (partition by item, timeperiod 
                       order by item, timeperiod, weeknum desc) as change
from table1;

ITEM    TIMEPERIOD   WEEKNUM   NUMBER   CHANGE
--
Bears   QTD          2013-26   67       12
Bears   QTD          2013-25   55       (null)
Bears   YTD          2013-26   132      12
Bears   YTD          2013-25   120      (null)
Cows    QTD          2013-26   7        2
Cows    QTD          2013-25   5        (null)
Cows    YTD          2013-26   9       -1
Cows    YTD          2013-25   10       (null)
Pigs    QTD          2013-26   28       6
Pigs    QTD          2013-25   22       (null)
Pigs    YTD          2013-26   86       6
Pigs    YTD          2013-25   80       (null)
```

If you want only those rows that have a negative change, use the previous query as a derived table, and add a WHERE clause

```
select *
from 
  (select 
      item, timeperiod, weeknum, number,
      number - lead (number) 
               over (partition by item, timeperiod 
                         order by item, timeperiod, weeknum desc) as change
  from table1) t
where change < 0
  and timeperiod = 'YTD';

ITEM    TIMEPERIOD   WEEKNUM   NUMBER   CHANGE
--
Cows    YTD          2013-26   9       -1
```

Comment: It isn't necessarily broken, it could be partitioned for performance reasons or to move older records to another storage. The DB could be holding billions of rows for all we know.

Comment: @jpw: Thanks. I moderated my language.